# Blender 2.8 Texture color error

Tags: texturing

[image: blender one]
[image: original one]

I made texture for box. But original texture (right) and imported texture on UV editor (left) are not same.
Why this color changing happens?

Answer (score 0):

I finally find the solution.

Properties editor -> Render -> Color Management

Changing the 'View Transform' to make post-render filtering.

[image]